# Springboot 2.0.2 - Resolving CORS for PUT and DELETE

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I have used the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in my RestController. All my `GET` requests are working well. But I am struggling with the `PUT` and `DELETE` requests.I get error :

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 405, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/api/delete/1", ok: false, …}
```

> Note that I am not using any authentication for the API

My Rest Controller ( Anotatted with `@CrossOrigin` on a class level):

```
//Rest Controller

@PutMapping(path = "edit/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void editRecipient(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                          @RequestBody RecipientEntity recipient){
    service.updateRecipient(id, recipient);
}

@DeleteMapping(path = "delete/{id}",  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void deleteRecipient(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws NotFoundException {
    service.deleteRecipient(id);
}
```

And here is my configurationg file :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(0);
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added this inside my controllers:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600L)
```

Also I've created a filter class, in this way:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * CORS filter for http-request and response
     */
    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    /**
     * Do Filter on every http-request.
     */
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "access_token, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy method
     */
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    /**
     * Initialize CORS filter
     */
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    }
}
```

And now all works!

I hope will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Add a component CORSFilter

```
@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, res);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

In spring config

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CORSFilter corsFilter;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(corsFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setName("corsFilter");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have looked at spring.io resources and other stack overflow issues related. I am not sure what am I missing. Are there any configs that I would already need to have in place to get the above code to work?

Comment: You can add class CORSFilter.java and config file WebConfig.java same code sample of me.

Comment: Same problem here (with 2.0.3). GET is OK but PUT and DELETE not working... Have news?

Comment: Please help to share your code and I will investigating for this problem ?